# Rasperry web server with CSS

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi and i want to configure a web server on it. I already configure it, I can already see it on my domain, but the website doesn't read the CSS file. 
P.S The path for the CSS file is right.
TY for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible to give more information on what sort of web server you are using? Apache? But I'm just gonna assume your rig is the same as mine. Please use the following code in your HTML.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css_file.css">
```

Comment: We had resolve the problem. It was a permission problem.